# Combine Git Bash and opening in current folder in CMDER

Tags: git, git-bash, cmder

Please describe me, who have such experience, how to correctly set the options of CMDER to open new console with Git Bash in current folder(Open CMDER here, for example). This string does not work:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -new_console:%__CD__%
```

I tried mix to this

```
""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
```

and this

```
cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" -new_console:%__CD__%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second option should have worked:

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/n3dst4/cc875d83401c06bd6faa) (also for [Cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder)):

> - Open Conemu
> - Open `Settings -> Tasks` or go to new tab button -> `Setup tasks`.
> - Click + to add a new task
> - Enter the name as Git Bash or whatever you like

Task parameters:

```
/icon "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git.ico" /dir "C:\_git"
```

Command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

> If you want to force your `$HOME` directory to be on local HD not network drive, you can do this as the command instead:

```
"set PATH=C:\Users\<username>;%PATH%" & "set HOME=C:\Users\Ndecarteret" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

This [tutorial is quite complete too](https://www.awmoore.com/2015/01/14/setting-up-git-and-cmder/).

Note: your case could be related to [issue 709](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/709#issuecomment-158489521).

Comment: A different example: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/635#issue-106122429

Comment: It works, but i want to open it not on the default folder such as "C:\Users\<username>", but in current folder like in this setting "cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" -new_console:%__CD__%"

For example: i call "Cmder here" in the folder D:\webworkers and i want to set this folder as start folder. Not to set it manualy using cd "whatever"

Comment: @Edymov And this does not work? https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/203#issuecomment-179222869

Comment: It works too, but i want to open with git bash, not on CMD like in this method.

Comment: @Edymov the cMD could in turn call git bash though.

Comment: Yes. i tested it today. It works fine not even with Git, but with many other utils. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I finished to use Git Bash

Comment: @Edymov OK, but what command line did you enter in CmdEr setting?

Comment: I an using CMD now throw the Cmder

Comment: @Edymov OK, I'll check if this is possible through Cmder alone.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script (set it as shortcut for example)

```
%windir%\system32\wscript.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\Git Bash.vbs" "PATH"
```

You simply have to use the `Git Bash.vbs` and pass it a path parameter to the desired folder. This is how the `git bash here` context menu works. pass $1 as the folder parameter.

---

### ***`--login`***

The `--login` command-line option passed to bash make it behave as a **"login shell"**

Comment: Sorry, @CodeWizard, but it not that i need. This way is simply launching Git Bash console app. I need to launch it in Cmder.