# Can I use cmder for Git Bash and other command line functions like dotnet, ng, etc at the same time?

Tags: bash, git, asp.net-core, cmd, cmder

I use cmder for `dotnet` and `ng` commands and for `Git` operations I use `Git Bash` command line. I think it it also possible to use `cmder` for `Git` operations on another tab. Is it possible to use the same cmder window with 4 tabs and run these 4 commands at the same time?

```
git checkout development

dotnet build 

ng serve --port 4200 

ipconfig
... (other command line operations)
```

I look at [Combine Git Bash and opening in current folder in CMDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675254/combine-git-bash-and-opening-in-current-folder-in-cmder) but I am not sure if it let me use these commands at the same time.

Comment: Just try it....

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I thought to try, but it may cause some bad consequences that can be realized later. For this reason before try, I wanted to be sure if it is a good idea. But as far as I see, I think no one else use this approach as there is no answer except from a comment.

Comment: Just try in some safe, test environment.

Comment: @Fredrick: From the [cmder home page](https://cmder.net/) I can see that you can even install cmder bundled fully with _git bash_. I don't think you will fall into damnation or suffer other bad consequences when playing around with console emulators. In the worst case, you find the console inconvenient to use or configure. There are many good alternatives consoles available for Windows, so just give it a try.

Comment: @user1934428 Ok, I will give a try, but I am not sure if I make any configuration changes to use it on cmder. By the way, I am using cmder full version.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : **Yes**.

---

Cmder comes pre-packed with git-bash, which in turn brings with it a lot of unix programs in the form of mingw. Cmder allows you to use in the same terminal session all your windows command line tools + the ones from Mingw. It even allows you to get powerful command line editing features through clink.

Also, you do not install cmder (at least the default way) you just [grab the archive you want to work with](https://cmder.net/), unarchive it, then run it. Your PATH will stay safe and only you can make the decision to either add it to your path or not.